# "\r\n" is ignored at csv file end

Tags: python, csv

```
import csv

impFileName = []
impFileName.append("file_1.csv")
impFileName.append("file_2.csv")

expFileName = "MasterFile.csv"
l = []
overWrite = False
comma = ","

for f in range(len(impFileName)):
    with open(impFileName[f], "r") as impFile:
        table = csv.reader(impFile, delimiter = comma)

        for row in table:
            data_1 = row[0]
            data_2 = row[1]
            data_3 = row[2]
            data_4 = row[3]
            data_5 = row[4]
            data_6 = row[5]

        dic = {"one":data_1, "two":data_2, "three":data_3, "four":data_4, "five":data_5, "six":data_6}

        for i in range(len(l)):
            if l[i]["one"] == data_1:
                print("Data, where one = " + data_1 + " has been updated using the data from " + impFileName[f])
                l[i] = dic
                overWrite = True
                break

        if overWrite == False:
            l.append(dic)
        else:
            overWrite = False
    print(impFileName[f] + " has been added to the list 'l'")

with open(expFileName, "a") as expFile:
    print("Master file now being created...")
    for i in range(len(l)):
        expFile.write(l[i]["one"] + comma + l[i]["two"] + comma + l[i]["three"] + comma + l[i]["four"] + comma + l[i]["five"] + comma + l[i]["six"] + "\r\n")

print("Process Complete")
```

This program takes 2 (or more) .csv files and compares the uniqueID (data_1) of each row to all others. If they match, it then assumes that the current row is an updated version so overwrites it. If there is no match then it's a new entry.

I store each row's data in a dictionary, which is then stored in the list "l".

Once all the files have been processed, I output the list "l" to the "MasterFile.csv" in the specified format.

---THE PROBLEM---
  The last row of "File_1.csv" and the first row of "File_2.csv" end up on the same line in the output file. I would like it to continue on a new line.

--Visual

```
...
data_1,data_2,data_3,data_4,data_5,data_6
data_1,data_2,data_3,data_4,data_5,data_6DATA_1,DATA_2,DATA_3,DATA_4,DATA_5,DATA_6
DATA_1,DATA_2,DATA_3,DATA_4,DATA_5,DATA_6
...
```

NOTE: There are no header rows in any of the .csv files.
  I've also tried this using only "\n" at the end of the "expFile.write" - Same result

Comment: The last line of the first file has no newline character, which is not uncommon. You have to manually insert one

Comment: Surely I am inserting them at the "expFile.Write" line near the bottom - at the end of the 'write' I insert "\r\n" ("\r" carriage return, "\n" line feed)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A'ight guys. I think I made a booboo.

1) Because I was using "a" (append) not "w" (write) at the end; and my last 2 or 3 tests I'd forgotten to clear the file, I was always looking at the same (top 50 or so) rows. Which meant I'd fixed my bug ages ago but was still looking at the old data....

2) Carriage returns were being read into the last value of the dictionary (data_6) so when they were appended to the Master file I ended up with "\r\r\n" at the end.

Thanks Vivek Srinivasan for expanding my python knowledge. I will look at pandas and have a play.

Thanks to MarianD for pointing out the "a"/"w" error.

Thanks to Moses Koledoye for pointing out the "\r" error.

Sorry for wasting your time.

Answer (score 1):

Just a little suggestion. Comparing two files in your way looks too expensive . Try using `pandas` in the following way.

```
import pandas
data1 = pandas.read_csv("file_1.csv")
data2 = pandas.read_csv("file_2.csv")

# Merging Two Dataframes 
combinedData = data1.append(data2,ignore_index=True)

# Dropping Duplicates
# give the name of the column on which you are comparing the uniqueness
uniqueData = combinedData.drop_duplicates(["columnName"])
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried running your program and it is OK. Your only problem is in the line

```
with open(expFileName, "a") as expFile:
```

where you use `"a"` (as append), so if you run your program again and again, it will *append* to this file.

Use `"w"` instead of `"a"`.